# how to Convert an ArrayList of Strings to an ArrayList of ArrayList of Strings with the same length strings grouped into a list together

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

I have an array list of strings (each individual element in the array list is just a word with no white space) and i want to group the same length elements in separate ArrayLists.

So say the array list has

```
element 0 = "abcd"
element 1 = "ansd,"
element 2 = "bac"
element 3 = "abc"
element 4 = "cab"
```

My result should be ArrayList(ArrayList(String))->{{"abcd","ansd"} , {"bac","abc","cab"}}

Comment: Requirements are not clear. Take sometime to explain it clearly. In your case its not list of list of string with same length.

Comment: In the above example, I want to create an ArrayList A, containing strings with length 4:{"abcd", "ansd"} and an ArrayList B,containing strings with length 3:{"bac","abc","cab"}. Both these ArrayLists A,B should be added inside another ArrayList C={ArrayList A, ArrayList B}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution. 
This problem is somewhat similar to finding the number of repeated characters in a String.
Here is the solution to my problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

ArrayList<String> A= new ArrayList<String>();
A.add("abc");
A.add("bac");
A.add("abcd");
A.add("cabd");

ArrayList(ArrayList(String)) C=new ArrayList(ArrayList(String))();

HashMap(Integer, ArrayList(String)) hm1= new HashMap(Integer, ArrayList(String))();

for (int i=0;i is less than A.size();i++){

    ArrayList<String> B;

    if (!hm1.containsKey(A.get(i).length())){
        B=new ArrayList<String>();
        B.add(A.get(i));
        hm1.put(Integer.valueOf(A.get(i).length()), B);

    }
    else
        hm1.get(A.get(i).length()).add(A.get(i));
}
for (Map.Entry m: hm1.entrySet()){

    C.add((ArrayList<String>) m.getValue());
}

}
```

If someone has a better solution then please post.